# similar to running table concept

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table, in that i want to update the closing balance of today should be shown as tomarrows opening balance, if any updation of closingbalance is taken place to particular date then from that date to current date opening balance should get updated, here is the sample output i want is as follows ; openingbalance(today)=closingbalance(yesterday)

```
date       opening_balance   closing_balance  accountformatid daybooktype
18-02-2013  12000               15000           1               240
19-02-2013  15000               14000           1               240
20-02-2013  14000               13000           1               240
21-02-2013  13000               10000           1               240
22-02-2013  10000               5000            1               240
23-02-2013  50000               1500            1               240
```

how could this acheived plz help me

Comment: Not clear. Clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (date DATETIME,      opening_balance  INT, closing_balance  INT,accountformatid INT,daybooktype INT)

INSERT @t 
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, a, 105), b,c,d,e
FROM (VALUES
('18-02-2013',12000  ,15000 ,1,240),
('19-02-2013',15000  ,14000 ,1,240),
('20-02-2013',14000  ,13000 ,1,240),
('21-02-2013',13000  ,10000 ,1,240),
('22-02-2013',10000  ,5000  ,1,240),
('23-02-2013',50000  ,1500  ,1,240)
) tbl(a,b,c,d,e)

SELECT  t1.*
        , t2.*
FROM    @t t1
LEFT JOIN   
        @t t2 ON t1.date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, t2.date)
AND     t1.opening_balance = t2.closing_balance
WHERE   t2.closing_balance IS NULL
-- this prevents first record to be falsely reported
AND     t1.date <> (SELECT MIN(date) FROM @t)
```

This lists the second of two subsequent records that don't correspond by date and balance.